# PostgreSQL "nested"? distincts and count 

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, distinct, postgresql-9.1

#### I need to get the count of the distinct names per hour in one query in PostgreSQL 9.1

The relevant columns(generalized for question) in my table are:

```
occurred timestamp with time zone and
name character varying(250)
```

And the table name for the sake of the question is just `table`

The `occurred` timestamps will all be within a midnight to midnight(exclusive) range for one day. So far my query looks like:

```
'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON (name)) FROM table'
```

It would be nice if I could get the output formatted as a list of 24 integers(one for each hour of the day), the names aren't required to be returned.

Comment: Thanks to all those who answered, I found out I had some data problems while testing your scripts, so I'm fixing that, then going to test and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this by hour:

```
select extract(hour from occurred) as hr, count(distinct name)
from table t
group by extract(hour from occurred)
order by 1
```

This assumes there is data for only one day.  Otherwise, hours from different days would be combined.  To get around this, you would need to include date information as well.

Comment: is table the table name or is t the table name?

Comment: @notbad.jpeg: `table` is the name and `t` is the *alias*

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', occurred) AS hour_slice
      ,count(DISTINCT name) AS name_ct
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

`DISTINCT ON` is a different feature.

`date_trunc()` gives you a sum for every distinct hour, while `EXTRACT` sums per hour-of-day over longer periods of time. The two results **do not add up**, because summing up multiple `count(DISTINCT x)` is equal or **greater** than one `count(DISTINCT x)`.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can write:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred),
       COUNT(DISTINCT name)
  FROM ...
 WHERE ...
 GROUP
    BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred)
 ORDER
    BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM occurred)
;
```

Comment: +1 for showing where to put extra parameters and nice capitalization